# Natbib - same author same year different coauthors - How to get the desired style in the in-text citation

Tags: bibtex, natbib

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[colon]{natbib}
\begin{document}

\citep{most2014a}
\citep{most2014b}

\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{ref}

\end{document}
```

this code will give me[image] and the bibiliography to be [image]

Is there a way I can make the in-text citation to be **(Mostaghimi et al., 2014a)** and **(Mostaghimi et al., 2014b)**?

The ref.bib includes,

```
@article{most2014a,
  title={A control volume finite element method for adaptive mesh simulation of flow in heap leaching},
  author={Mostaghimi, Peyman and Tollit, Brendan S and Neethling, Stephen J and Gorman, Gerard J and Pain, Christopher C},
  journal={Journal of Engineering Mathematics},
  volume={87},
  number={1},
  pages={111--121},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@Article{most2014b,
  author    = {Mostaghimi, Peyman and Ilankoon, I. M. Saman K. and Neethling, Stephen J.},
  title     = {{Use of mesh adaptivity in simulation of flow in packed beds - A case study}},
  journal   = {Minerals Engineering},
  year      = {2014},
  volume    = {63},
  pages     = {157--163},
  issn      = {08926875},
  isbn      = {0892-6875},
  keywords  = {Computational modelling,Control volume finite element methods,Mesh adaptivity,Multiphase flow,Packed beds},
  publisher = {Elsevier Ltd},
}
```

I want to use natbib/agsm (because I want to get the bibliography in the sttached style) and to make the uniquenames go away. But cannot find a way to do it. Appreciate if anyone can help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You've come across an admittedly uncommon design feature of the `agsm` bibliography style: If two or more cited entries each have three or more authors, of which the first author is common across entries, `agsm` will *not* truncate the lists contained in the citation call-outs. If you can't abide this feature, it's probably best to start looking for a different bib style.

Comment: Thanks Mico for your direction. I however looked for alternatives such as,
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,natbib=true,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
But the bibliography is not the same I want..

Comment: May I suggest that you post a query in which you (a) describe your precise formatting requirements and (b) ask for suggestions for an existing bibliography style that either fully or mostly meets your requirements? Alternatively, you could look into the `makebst` utility, which is part of the `custom-bib` package. The utility poses a lot of questions about formatting elements, each with several possible answers; the *output* of this utility is a bespoke bibliography style file.